# mod_rewrite  - Internal Server Error 500

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod_rewrite, php

Всем привет!

Не могу разобраться с mod_rewrite в htaccess. Я изначально избавился от расширения путем - `RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.php` ->  получилось. Теперь хочу получить  `http://site.ru/site_.php?page=pety` на `http://site.ru/pety` - делаю ЧПУ - `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ site_.php?page=$1 [L]` ->  ошибка! Internal Server Error 500 (почему??)

Весь htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.php  
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ site_.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(\w+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^site_.php$ %1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: ( не получается
на запрос: http://site.ru/pety -> ошибка 404 Not Found